# How to convert a Python code to IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I would know if there's a possibility to adapt a Python code to Ironpython to control a DC power supply.

I want to control a DC power supply with ironpython, but first I've tried with Python and it worked, the problem is when I want to run it in IronPython, it doesn't work.

```
import time
with serial.Serial('COM27', 9600) as ser:
    ser.write(b'Output on\n')
    ser.write(b'Volt 13.5\n')
    time.sleep(3)
    ser.write(b'Volt 5\n')
    time.sleep(3)
    ser.write(b'Volt 13.5\n')
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What's the error traceback and what's the expected output?

Comment: [pySerial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) is a third-party extension module and not part of the Python standard-library, so it may not be usable from ironpython.

Comment: @rassar The expected output is make changes in the voltage on a Keysight DC power supply through ironpython.